# TFS Merge - Make sure to include all changes

Tags: tfs, merge

I have server workspace. Our branches are like below

Source

- Development

  - Branch1
- Main

My task is to merge Main into Branch1. I did the following

Get latest code for Main

Get latest code for Branch1

Merge Main to Branch1. After auto merge, I resolved conflicts by

Few conflicts I take source version ( Main )

Few conflicts I take target version ( Branch1)

Few conflicts I manually resolve them.

I build my Branch1 code and run my application to make sure that my merge didnot break our application in Branch1.

When I open Pending Changes in Team explorer, I see **Included Changes 188 out of 14187**.
I am confused alot since I am expecting *Included Changes 14187 out of 14187.* so that **I donot miss any files** when I check in Branch1.

Can anybody let me know whether I am doing anything wrong and let me know how to make sure that I check in all changes or **Included Changes 188 out of 14187** is correct or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the text. *188 out of 14187* is the number of files with pending changes **being displayed**. There should be a link to view all of the changes in a flat view instead of the normal tree view. If you perform a check-in, all 14187 changes will be checked in.

I also wanted to note that the behavior you're seeing is unique to the Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2012 -- VS2013 will just show you everything, all the time.

Comment: Yes, I saw "Go To All Changes" link and when I click it, it goes to a display to show all flies. Before I check-in I want to make sure that I merge all files and doesnot miss any. Yes, I am using VS 2012.

Comment: I will finish my merge and follow this and will let you know. If it solves my issue will mark it as answer

Comment: Hi dan - we are having a problem and decided to merge QA to branch1. But I am unable to undo all my pending changes that happened when I did merge Main to Branch1. Please see this link for my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803830/tfs-discard-un-checked-merge-changes  I will keep you updated

Comment: I am marking this answer since when I checked in all my pending changes got checked in. This helped me to clarify my doubt. Thanks Daniel.